# How to implement geofence triggered local notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, geofencing

I've created a simple geofence based application to monitor the movement of people entering and exiting a geofence and I'm trying to send a notification on these events but can't seem to implement it correctly.

I would really appreciate some explained sample code which would go in the view controller and app delegate.

P.s My knowledge of swift is somewhat limited but I understand most aspects necessary for this application.
Thanks for any help!

Edit:

This is my function for creating the notification which I think is correct.

```
func scheduleNotification() {
    let centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.364730, -0.189986)
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: centre, radius: 150, identifier: "SGS")
    region.notifyOnEntry = true

    let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: true)

    let enterContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    enterContent.title = "Enter"
    enterContent.body = "Entered premesis"
    enterContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let enterRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "enterNotification", content: enterContent, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(enterRequest) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }      
}
```

I added this to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {(accepted, error) in
        if !accepted {
            print("Notification access denied.")
        }
    }
```

I know I need to call the function but I don't know where to do it so that it is called when the geofence is left. Also I'm not sure how to call it from the view controller as it is in the AppDelegate.

Sorry if I'm being stupid but thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the location manager's [didEnterRegion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423560-locationmanager) and [didExitRegion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423630-locationmanager) delegate methods. Within your implementation of those methods is where you'll post the local notifications.

If you've already done that, make sure that the app has the proper capibility for posting notifications, and that you've registered the proper notification settings for the app in the app delegate.

Ray Wenderlich has a good [tutorial on Geofencing](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial) and [here's Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html) on local and remote push notifications.

Comment: so instead of using the extra function I should just put that code within the didEnterRegion/didExitRegion?

Comment: Right. didEnterRegion and didExitRegion get automatically called by the location manager when it notices that the device is entering or exiting one of the set regions. Since that is when you want to send the local notification, it would make sense to create and send them from there.